# What exactly does a connection pool for databases like PostgreSQL do?

Tags: postgresql, connection-pooling, haproxy, pgbouncer, pgpool

I know the general idea that a connection pool is a pool of reusable connections that speeds up traffic to the database because it can reuse connections instead of constantly creating new ones.

But this is a very high level explanation. It doesn't explain what is meant by a connection and why the connection pool works, since even with a connection pool such as for example `client -> PgBouncer -> PostgreSQL`, while the client does not have to create a connection to the databasee, it still has to connect to create a connection to the proxy.

So what is the connection created from (e.g.) `client -> PgBouncer` and why is creating this connection faster than creating the connection `PgBouncer -> PostgreSQL`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two uses of a connection pool:

- it prevents opening and closing database connections all the time

  There is certainly a certain overhead with establishing a TCP connection to pgBouncer, but that is *way cheaper* than establishing a database connection. When you start a database connection, additional work is done:

  - a server process is started, which is way more expensive than a TCP connection
  - PostgreSQL loads cached metadata tables
- it puts a limit on the number of client connections, thereby preventing database overload

  The advantage over limiting `max_connections` is that connections in excess of the limit won't receive an error, but will be queued waiting for a connection to become free.